# Symbol of matrix norm

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

[image]

What does this symbol mean? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF4wf.png)

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Some authors use it for the operator norm to the Euclidean norm. Some authors use it for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thank you guys! I am just really confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) $\|\cdot\|_p$ is defined as

$$\|A\|_p := \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}$$

where both norms on the right side are vector norms.

In the case of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ one has $\|x\|_p:=\sqrt[p]{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p}$

In the specific case of $p=2$ this is the [euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{|x_1|^2 + \dots + |x_n|^2}$

The superscript $2$ in $\|A\|_2^2$ is simply an exponent, $\|A\|_2^2 = (\|A\|_2)^2$

Other equivalent ways of expressing the norm exist and can be found on the linked wiki article.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just inserted another picture in the question. Does the equation mean that $(‖Qx‖_2)^2 = (‖x‖_2)^2$, where Q is a matrix and x is a vector?

Comment: In this specific case, yes, because of the special properties that $Q$ exhibits.  In your second picture, it is probably the case that $Q$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).  It is not usually the case that $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$

Comment: So basically, $(‖A‖_2)^2$ is the square of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$?

Comment: Or singular value as the case may be

Comment: could you take a look at the example that dantopa provides in the comments below his answer? Is that correct? According to your answer, it should be 9.

Comment: My answer itself wasn't incorrect, it was just my comment that was unclear because I didn't tell you outright that your question in the comments was wrong.  $\|A\|_2^2$ is indeed the square of the largest singular value of $A$ and is the largest eigenvalue (*in cardinality*) (*not the square of the largest eigenvalue*) of $A^*A$.  I blame that on myself in thinking in terms of singular values and not noticing right away that your comment was slightly off.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the matrix two norm, an extension of the vector norm described by @JMoravitz.

If so, then
$$
\lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2}^{2} = \sigma_{1}
$$
where $\sigma_{1}$ is the largest singular value of $\mathbf{A}$, which is also the largest eigenvalue of the product matrix: 
$$
\lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2}^{2} = \lambda_{max}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right).
$$

Comment: So in the second equation, does $A*$ mean the transpose of matrix A?

Comment: According to @JMoravitz, that means the $(‖A‖_2)^2$, which is the square of the largest eigenvalue of $A$. Is it the same as the largest eigenvalue of the product matrix?

Comment: @J.doe: Apologies for the notation: $\mathbf{A}^{*} = \bar{\mathbf{A}}^{\mathrm{T}}$, the transpose of the complex conjugate. If the matrix is real, this is just the transpose.

Comment: @J.doe: Caution. The second formula in the response is correct. The statement "...which is the square of the largest eigenvalue of A" is not correct.

Comment: Wait.. Isn't the right side of the second equation the definition of 2 norm of matrices? So are you suggesting that $‖A‖_2$ and $(‖A‖_2)^2$ are the same?

Comment: The $\mathbf{Q}$ matrix is probably unitary. In that case $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{Q}^{*}=\mathbf{Q}^{*}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{I}$.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{A}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]$. $\lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2}^{2} = 3$.

Comment: For this matrix, its 2 norm is also 3. So they are the same?

Comment: $\lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2} = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Is the definition of 2 norm of the matrix "The maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$"?

Comment: @J.doe it is the maximum *singular value* of $A$ which corresponds to the *square root* of the maximum (*in cardinality*) eigenvalue of $A^*A$.  Remember that $\|x\|_2$ is the *square root* of the sum of the squares of the entries, so even ignoring all this talk about eigenvalues and singular values, you see that for this specific example $\|Ax\|$ is maximized for unit vector $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]^T$ with output $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]^T$ and 2-norm $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{3}$